# Data binding not working - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Somehow, I am unable to display the data from my backend in the component. Console logging response.data gives me my data. I put it in the movies variable within the scope, but it doesn't bind. Here is the code:

INDEX.HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Movies - AngularJS</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="app">²
        <div class="box" ng-repeat="movie in movies">
            <h2 ng-class="movie.genre">{{ movie.genre }}</h2>
            <h1>{{ movie.title }}</h1>
            <p>Change the values of the movie.</p>
            <input ng-change="onChange" ng-model="movie.title" type="text">
            <input ng-change="onChange" ng-model="movie.genre" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>  
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MAIN.JS FILE

```
const app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/movies`)
        .then(response => {
        $scope.movies = response.data;
        console.log($scope.movies); // logs the data correctly 
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e.message));
});
```

I think it has something to do with Async/sync'ness but I don't know how to solve it. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Wrap `$scope.movies = response.data` in `$scope.$apply()`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see any issues with your code, probably you need to force the rendering manually using **`$scope.$apply();`**

```
$scope.movies = response.data;
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use angular `$http` instead of `axios` to make your requests since it will internally call for view digest when you update scope within callbacks

Any time you use code outside of angular context to update scope you need to tell angular to run a digest

Also will remove axios as unnecessary dependency to load in page since `$http` already exists in angularjs core

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense. Axios won't do anything that `$http` won't

Comment: No because angular has that functionality built in and if you want honest comparison should use what the framework offers without needing hacks to use axios. A better comparison would be to use more current angular 5 or 6 which is completely different than angularjs (v1.xxx)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `axios` and wrapping your angular `$scope` inside it, the digest cycle is unable to read that change

Use, angular's  `$http` instead of `axios`

**OR**

If you want to use `axios` then, you can use `$scope.$apply` and wrap `$scope.movies = response.data`; inside it.

like

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
                   $scope.movies = response.data;
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell angularjs to update - call

```
$scope.$evalAsync();
```

after set data